# Converting iPhone to Universal

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to convert this app i have from iPhone to iPad.. i've set the logic properly but i get bad excess error. Here is the code.

```
 SortingILove *controller = nil;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        controller = [[SortingILove alloc] initWithNibName:@"SortingILove-iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    else
    {
        myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        myTableView.delegate = self;
        myTableView.dataSource = self;

        itemsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [itemsList addObject:@" attracted to Places"];
        [itemsList addObject:@" in love with Shopping"];
        [itemsList addObject:@" alive for Food"];

        self.navigationItem.title = @"";
        self.view = myTableView;
        self.tableView.rowHeight=123;
        self.tableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.jpg"];
        UIImageView *backgroundViews = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
        [self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundViews];
    }


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
    //tableView.backgroundView = backgroundViews;
    //[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Comment: That error appears for bot iphone and ipad?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Do you get the error when running on iPhone, iPad or both? Have you run with NSZombieEnabled?

Comment: oh sorry, for both iPhone and iPad, it crashes... ever since i added UIUserInterfaceIdion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code you are only alloc-init your **controller** for iPad, for the iPhone, you do not allocate it and then when it comes to a line `[controller release];` it has nothing to release!

Comment: thanks @Ladislav... i was trying stuff and got confused, thank you for the reminder :D